# Although all required configuration is done in iPhone for recording script in jmeter, recording is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, jmeter, certificate, recording

iphone configuration:

1. valid certification is installed
2. Proxy is set as required(laptop's ip and port as 8088 same as in jmeter)
3. Phone/laptop/Jmeter restart all tried multiple times

Although all configuration is done as required, recording does not start. Anything I am missing?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuPWH.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems valid so I don't have any other suggestions than:

1. Ensure that the certificate is not expired (it's valid for 7 days only, as long as you didn't touch [`proxy.cert.validity` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)) and it's the same one that in JMeter's "bin" folder
2. As it evidenced by its name the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic, if your application uses other/different network protocols you will not be able to record it (at least not with JMeter 5.4.1)
3. Check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries. It would also be a good idea to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the proxy and friends, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   ```
4. And last but not the least check your [iPhone logs](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/obtain-ios-device-logs-using-mac-and-windows/)